How to update the json key and keep value as it is
Original
{
  "Table": "admin.lookup",
  "New ABC Table": "SQL_ABC_Test_DP",
  "Package Bucket": "",
  "Storage Bucket": "",
  "ABC Table selector": "false",
  "Existing ABC Table": "",
  "Migrated Table Name": "SQL_ABC_Test_DP"
}

update user_portal.pipeline_config set auth_config = replace(auth_config::text, 'ABC', 'abc')::jsonb
after above query it is updated
{
  "Table": "admin.lookup",
  "New abc Table": "SQL_abc_Test_DP",
  "Package Bucket": "",
  "Storage Bucket": "",
  "abc Table selector": "false",
  "Existing abc Table": "",
  "Migrated Table Name": "SQL_abc_Test_DP"
}

Now after appying the above query in json key is change but also values also changes  then what should i do for it then only key are change how to update the query
I want
{
} "Table": "admin.lookup",
  "New abc Table": "SQL_ABC_Test_DP",
  "Package Bucket": "",
  "Storage Bucket": "",
  "abc Table selector": "false",
  "Existing abc Table": "",
  "Migrated Table Name": "SQL_ABC_Test_DP"

How to update the json key and keep value as it is

This looks like PostgreSQL ! please tag the correct DBMS

Remove the old key and append new with the value of the old. PostgreSQL : update user_portal.pipeline_config set auth_config = (auth_config - 'New ABC Table') || jsonb_build_object('New abc Table', auth_config['New ABC Table'])
